# I'm looking for a copy utility for OS X that will tell me exactly what is being copied at the moment as well as what has been completed already

Tags: macos, finder

I think the title says it all. I'm looking for a copy utility/Finder plugin for OS X that will tell me exactly what file(s) is/are being copied at the moment (from and to included, of course).

A history of what has been 100% completed already wouldn't be bad but I can do that by comparing directories.

Answer (score 3):

If you are comfortable using the Terminal.app for copying files instead of finder, the cp (copy) command has an option to show the files being copied.  The list of previously copied files would be displayed.  The "-v" option stands for "verbose".

```
$>  cp -vr Messages /tmp/Messages
Messages -> /tmp/Messages
Messages/118942.emlx -> /tmp/Messages/118942.emlx
Messages/122810.emlx -> /tmp/Messages/122810.emlx
Messages/126942.emlx -> /tmp/Messages/126942.emlx
Messages/127552.emlx -> /tmp/Messages/127552.emlx
Messages/133765.emlx -> /tmp/Messages/133765.emlx
Messages/133912.emlx -> /tmp/Messages/133912.emlx
Messages/134148.emlx -> /tmp/Messages/134148.emlx
Messages/43442.emlx -> /tmp/Messages/43442.emlx
Messages/43443.emlx -> /tmp/Messages/43443.emlx
Messages/51858.emlx -> /tmp/Messages/51858.emlx
Messages/51859.emlx -> /tmp/Messages/51859.emlx
Messages/51860.emlx -> /tmp/Messages/51860.emlx
Messages/51861.emlx -> /tmp/Messages/51861.emlx
Messages/86518.emlx -> /tmp/Messages/86518.emlx
Messages/86905.emlx -> /tmp/Messages/86905.emlx
Messages/9164.2.emlxpart -> /tmp/Messages/9164.2.emlxpart
Messages/9164.emlx -> /tmp/Messages/9164.emlx
$>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feed back but I'd prefer to work in the domain of GUI's. Lazy I guess :-)